# Specified cast is not valid error in Datagridview c#

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

This is a really weird error I've never had before. I have added a checkbox to my datagridview like this:

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkBoxColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
datagrid.Columns.Insert(0, checkBoxColumn);
```

I get the error

> Specified cast is not valid

And it highlights this in cell formating of the datagrid:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= this.datagrid.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if ((int)datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value <= 5)
    {
        this.datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
```

This checks if a value in cell 7 is below the value or equal to 5 and if it is changes it to red. I have tried changing the cell to 8 because I thought it had moved since I've added a new column at 0 however it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `int.TryParse` which will only parse the cell's value if it can be successfully parsed to an `int`.  Like this:

```
int temp;

for (int i = 0; i <= this.datagrid.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{        
    if (int.TryParse(datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value.ToString(), out temp) == true) 
    {
         if (temp <= 5)
         {
             this.datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
         }
    }
```

At the very least this will stop throwing an exception and you can determine if your cell formatting is working correctly or not. I'm guessing you have a row in your data set that has a bad or null value in column 7 and/or 8.  If you added this new checkbox column at position zero then you will need to now reference `.Cells[8]`.

A better way to reference columns is by their name.  Then if you add or delete columns in the future you don't mess up the rest of your column index references throughout your code.  Try this if you get the above working:

```
if (int.TryParse(datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["yourColumnName"].Value, out temp) == true)
```

In order to use this method, you must specify the `.Name` column when you create and add the columns.

Comment: Hello, I have tried your solution but I have the following errors: `The best overloaded method match for 'int.TryParse(string, out int)' has some invalid arguments` and `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'`

Comment: See my edit above.  You need to .ToString() your cell's value.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! That works! Could you possibly tell me why it started giving me the error when I added the checkbox and without the checkbox my old code worked fine?

Comment: Without knowing your columns types/controls and what kind of data is in your grid it is hard to know.  Check that your data is clean from null values as int.TryParse() just skips any cells and rows that it can't parse.  With your code above, it only takes one record in your dataset to cause the exception you were getting.  And focus on columns at index 7 and 8 as those are the two columns that you are now referencing.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
for (int i = 0; i <= this.datagrid.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value) <= 5)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Yes, but do use ToInt32(). Int16 is for special occasions.

Comment: I have got this error `Input string was not in a correct format.`

Comment: Can you try and see what this gives : `datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value.ToString()` gives or add a watch to `datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value` and see what value does it holds?

Comment: by the way, when are you calling the cell formatting method? can you please post the whole code?

Comment: ok, and when are you adding the `CheckBox`? Before or after formatting?

Comment: I've added checkbox where I am binding the datagrid to get the data from database.

Comment: Then the position of the columns are moved one step further. Try with `.Cells[8].Value`

Comment: Unfortunately it's still doesn't like it. I have commented out the cell formatting code to make sure the cell was 8 and it was however it's still giving the Input String error

Comment: we cannot help without knowing the whole code... and the full Exception details